# Como evitar o uso de Service Locator em meu Unit Of Work com Contextos Delimitados e MediatR?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ddd

Olá,

Estou iniciando estudos em DDD e contextos delimitados e gostaria de evitar o uso de Service Locator para acessar meus repositórios através do Unit of Work.

No momento estou usando MediatR para receber uma mensagem de Query e resolvê-la (é um projeto API):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<UsuarioDTO>> Get([FromQuery]PegarUsuarioPorNomeDeUsuarioQuery nomeDeUsuarioQuery)
    {
        try
        {
            UsuarioDTO usuario = await _Mediator.Send(nomeDeUsuarioQuery);
            if (usuario == null)
                return NotFound("Usuário não encontrado");
            else
                return Ok(usuario);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

O handler para essa Query se encontra no meu Contexto de Segurança (uma class library):

```
namespace SegurancaBC.Handlers.Queries
{
    public class PegarUsuarioPorNomeDeUsuarioHandler : IRequestHandler<PegarUsuarioPorNomeDeUsuarioQuery, UsuarioDTO>
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _UoW;

        public PegarUsuarioPorNomeDeUsuarioHandler(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            _UoW = uow;
        }

        public async Task<UsuarioDTO> Handle(PegarUsuarioPorNomeDeUsuarioQuery request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            IUsuarioRepository usuarioRepository = _UoW.PegarRepositorio<IUsuarioRepository>(); // implementado com Service Locator internamente
            UsuarioDTO usuario = await usuarioRepository.CarregarUsuario(new Email(request.NomeDeUsuario));
            return usuario;
        }
    }
}
```

**Este ponto me deixa preocupado**, pois o "PegarRepositorio" usa um service locator para invocar a implementação correta de IUsuarioRepository que eu tenha definido na camada de Infraestrutura.

Neste momento tenho um projeto *SharedKernel* com uma interface para o *UoW*:

```
namespace SharedKernel.Repositories
{
    public interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        void Begin();
        void Commit();
        void RollBack();
        TRepositorio PegarRepositorio<TRepositorio>() where TRepositorio : IRepository;

        IDbConnection Connection { get; }
        IDbTransaction Transaction { get; }
    }
}
```

Abaixo a implementação específica com o Service Locator:

```
    public TRepositorio PegarRepositorio<TRepositorio>() where TRepositorio : IRepository
    {
        Type tipoRepositorio = typeof(TRepositorio);
        return (TRepositorio)_ServiceProvider.GetService(tipoRepositorio);
    }
```

Em cada Contexto eu tenho diferentes Repositórios, como:

```
namespace SegurancaBC.Domain.Repositories
{
    public interface IUsuarioRepository : IRepository
    {
        Task<UsuarioDTO> CarregarUsuario(Email nomeDeUsuario);
        Task InserirUsuario(Usuario usuario);
        Task AtivarUsuario(Email nomeDeUsuario);
        Task InativarUsuario(Email nomeDeUsuario);
    }
}
```

E suas devidas implementações numa camada de Infraestrutura (não estou criando uma infra por cada contexto).

Se eu não me preocupasse com separação de classes em contextos, poderia simplesmente ditar que minha interface do UoW tivesse um get para o IUsuarioRepository, mas nesse cenário, causaria uma dependência circular, visto que meu contexto de "Segurança" também depende do "Shared Kernel".

Vendo outro cenário, criando uma infraestrutura e uma API para cada contexto, esse problema também seria evitado pois poderia especializar minha UoW para cada Infra, mas acredito que isto levaria a um caminho mais complexo do que desejo abordar no momento (Micro serviços?).

Sempre vejo que Service Locator é um anti pattern, mas no momento, não consigo ver uma solução sem essa abordagem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questões envolvendo **patterns** e **arquiteturas** dificilmente possuem uma única resposta correta e a discussão pode facilmente se tornar opiniativa, então o que devemos fazer é entender o contexto da implementação e chegar numa solução escalável que atenda aos requisitos que possuí.

Isso ganha ainda mais ênfase quando falando do **Unit Of Work Pattern**, pois o próprio exemplo de [implementação da microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#implement-a-generic-repository-and-a-unit-of-work-class) é diferente ao [UML proposto por Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) que é quem concebeu o pattern. A própria microsoft afirma no link acima, que há várias implementações diferentes, e não necessariamente incorretas, para esse pattern.

Analisando a estrutura da sua pergunta, fica claro que sua atual implementação está seguindo o modelo da Microsoft, onde a classe `Unit Of Work` é responsável por guardar e fornecer os repositórios com que ela trabalha.

Se você deseja seguir esse formato, não recomendo utilizar `Service Locator` para retornar os repositórios, não por ele ser considerado um anti-pattern, mas devido à falta de coerência: O objetivo de armazenar os repositórios no estado da classe de `UnitOfWork` [é segregar os repositórios cujas operações, irão utilizar o Context daquela UnitOfWork](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application#creating-the-unit-of-work-class). Ao utilizar `Service Locator` para essa responsabilidade, **não temos mais controle** sobre quais repositórios aquela `UoW` está gerenciando.

Obviamente essa situação poderia ser contornada criando `containers de DI` com as dependências dos repositórios isolados, ou resolvendo todos os `Repositórios` de uma vez, e adicionando-os à uma lista interna na classe `UoW`. Mas é questionável o ganho dessa abordagem, afinal, embora estejamos resolvendo o problema do uso incorreto, ainda estamos deixando a classe sem indicações clara do que ela possuí, sendo necessário sempre checar sua implementação para saber quais repositórios ela comporta.

Se o objetivo for seguir por esse caminho, acho preferível a estrutura proposta no tutorial da microsoft:

Exemplo:

```
interface IUnitOfWork
{
    public IUsuarioRepository UsuarioRepository { get; }
    // outros repositórios
    public void Save();
}
```

Nesse formato, você terá que criar uma nova interface para cada diferente `DbContext`, como `ISegurancaUnitOfWork` , `IProdutosUnitOfWork`. Mas se de toda forma você está utilizando uma `camada de Infraestrutura` compartilhada, o benefício da **coerência** é superior à poucas linhas de código que seriam poupadas.

Espero ter ajudado, abraços!

Comment: muito obrigado pela cordialidade e pela indicação, seguirei nos estudos!